# Adding Firebase Analytics to NextJS 13 app/pages

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js13, firebase-analytics

What's the correct way to add firebase analytics to a nextJS 13 app? most of the docs or posts are of before nextJS v13 app/pages.
I have added a firebase.ts file and added the following

```
"use client";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { firebaseConfig } from "./src/configs/firebase.config";

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Analytics and get a reference to the service
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

export { app, analytics };
```

And in one of my layout components, I have added this useEffect

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") logEvent(analytics, "page_view");
  }, []);
```

I am getting the following error in server

> @firebase/analytics: Analytics: Firebase Analytics is not supported in this environment. Wrap initialization of analytics in analytics.isSupported() to prevent initialization in unsupported environments. Details: (1) Cookies are not available. (analytics/invalid-analytics-context).

I have tried removing the use client, but I get window is not defined error. How to add firebase properly in NextJS?

Answer (score 1):

Use `isSupported`. [from here](https://modularfirebase.web.app/reference/analytics/)

> This is a public static method provided to users that wraps four
> different checks:
>
> 1. Check if it's not a browser extension environment.
> 2. Check if cookies are enabled in current browser.
> 3. Check if IndexedDB is supported by the browser environment.
> 4. Check if the current browser context is valid for using IndexedDB.open().

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics, isSupported } from "firebase/analytics";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let analytics;
isSupported().then((_)=>{ analytics = getAnalytics(app)}).catch((e)=>console.warn("Analytics is not supported in this environment.",e.message))
```

Comment: this returns a promise. It cant be use in that way

Comment: also if there's a step by step guide, on how to do this, would have been helpful

Comment: if it returns promise, you can use `then/catch` chian on Promise

Comment: if I do that, I get the error analytics doesn't have any type. Now If I set ``` let analytics : Analytics ```, I get the error ```cannot read properties of undefined (reading app)``` in my useEffect. 
It's a hassle.

Comment: also if there is anyway I can check locally my firebase analytics is working? or do I need to check it in firebase?